Calculation based on 2 Years selected from slicers
I'm still new with Power BI Desktop and I have one scenario where I have current and previous years as two slicers which user should select. and based on that the calculation should be subtraction of values.
example:



Value
Date




200
28-Dec-22


345
05-Dec-23


500
29-Dec-18


980
13-Dec-19


441
22-Dec-20



If user select previous year as (28-Dec-22) and current year (05-Dec-23) the calculation will be (calculation=345-200) the value of year 28-Dec-22 minus the value of year 05-Dec-23

could any one please help!
I couldn't find any solution to help

In order for this to work, you should use Calendar dimension.
I used only one slicer - for Current year value, and previous year will be based on this Current year. If you need to calculate longer gap, e.g. Current Year 2023 - Previous Year 2021, measure should be different.
Instead of using date, I used year in the slicer, coming from Calendar.
I created 3 measures:
Selected Year Value = SUM('Table'[Value])

Prev Year Value = CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Value]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Calendar'[Date]) )

Diff =  [Prev Year Value] - [Selected Year Value]


